# Linear equations simultaneously prime

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following small problem using only elementary methods or not-so-recent theorems. The result follows from [a theorem by Green and Tao](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606088) (Corollary 1.9) which solves a more general case with sophisticated methods.

Let $\psi_i(\alpha) = \alpha_x x_i + \alpha_y y_i$ where $\alpha = (\alpha_x, \alpha_y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2,x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{Z}, i = 1,2$ be two linear functions $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with suitable good properties on the $x_i,y_i$ (e.g. $\gcd(x_1,x_2) = \gcd(y_1,y_2) = \gcd(x_i,y_i) = 1$). Then exists infinitely many $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $\psi_i(\alpha)$ are all primes.

The problem is the "next case" (two equations) of Bezout identity (one equation: if $\gcd(x_i,y_i) = 1$ then obviously $\psi_i(\alpha)$ assumes infinitely many prime values), so I'm hoping for older known results or simpler solutions.

Comment: We do NOT know whether there are infinite many positive integera $x$ , such that , say , $2x+1$ and $3x+1$ are both prime. This is only conjectured. Not sure which result you actually mean.

Comment: The mentioned theorem only guarantees the existence of arbitary long nontrivial arithmetic sequences consisting of only primes (not necessarily consecutive). But if we want longer sequences we will have to increase the difference more and more.

Comment: @Peter I might be mistaken, but $2x+1$ and $3x+1$ have quite a different complexity than $2x+3y$ and $5x+7y$ (infinite and $0$ respectively?) - which is exactly the main assumption of the theorem.